# spring-boot-starter-parent pom not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: spring-boot, maven

After getting a new laptop, I am facing this issue very frequently, the spring dependencies particulary spring boot is not getting downloaded, the message that I got was

```
[ERROR]   The project com.john:EmployeeH2Demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\John\IdeaProjects\EmployeeH2Demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.john:EmployeeH2Demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5
.2 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolutio
n is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ li
ne 6, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

First I did not had settings.xml but it was not working then I checked the url https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 this url did not had spring-boot-starter-parent, and when I googled I could find spring-boot dependency in this repo http://www.mvnrepository.com, so I tried using that repo, resulting in the below settings.xml

Here is my settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
<offline>false</offline>
<pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>mvnrepository</id>
                <name>mvnrepository</name>
                <url>http://www.mvnrepository.com</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mvnrepository</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

and here is the pom.xml for this project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.john</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeH2Demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Demo Project for H2 in memory database using SpringBoot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>>
```

But even after several attems to clean build the project, I am not able to do it.

After removing the settings.xml from the .m2 directory, still getting the following error.

```
$ mvn clean install -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.
5.2.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.bablo:EmployeeH2Demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-boot-starter-pare
nt:pom:2.5.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.john:EmployeeH2Demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\bablo\IdeaProjects\EmployeeH2Demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.bablo:EmployeeH2Demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-boo
t-starter-parent:pom:2.5.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 13
 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I am not behind a proxy, neither I am using a vpn or anything like that.

Also on checking on the url being hit by maven to download the spring-boot-starter-parent, that is this url,

[https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.
5.2.pom](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.2/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.%205.2.pom)

nothing is there at that location, can I not get any other url to be searched by maven, to download spring-boot-starter-parent dependency.

Comment: Remove the `settings.xml` completely. Apart from that `http://www.mvnrepository.com` is no usable Maven repository...

Comment: Removed it, but the error persists.

Comment: Clean your local cache. Delete your .m2 directory and recreate again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<groupId>` of the `<parent>` in your pom is incorrect. You have `org.springframework`. It should be `org.springframework.boot`.

Comment: Thanks, I also figured it out, but before I could post, you have given the correct answer, thanking you and accepting your answer

Answer (score 1):

Very trivial error, sorry guys but the issue was that I was not giving the correct group id org.springframework.boot, so the correct pom is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.john</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeH2Demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Demo Project for H2 in memory database using SpringBoot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```